# Python Queue initialization delay

Tags: python, initialization, queue, multiprocessing, delay

have some python code that uses 'multiprocessing' Queues to process some info in permanent separate processes. I measure the time it takes to process the info in each Process.

The weird thing is that the first item to get processed  takes about 10 times longer than any other item that follows, so about 5 seconds compared to subsequent items of about .5 seconds.

I have looked at where the delay comes from and it seems to be using the Queue for the first time.

Does anybody know if there is a defined overhead in setting up the Queue? Is this first time delay documented or am I doing something wrong?

```
def f(q): 
  while 1:
    data = q.get(block=True) # need to wait for an input
    log(time.time())   # <-- first time 5 sec delay, after that min delay
     ....

def get(data):
  log(time.time()    
  q.put(data, False)

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=f, args=(q, ))
p.daemon = True
p.start()
get(data)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem.  Which OS are you using?  Maybe you are just measuring the time it takes for the worker process to spawn (should be less than 5 sec, though...)?

Comment: thanks Ferdinand, I will put together some reproducible code and post it here. It's def not a delay in spawning because that happens earlier. Using Centos 5.7

Comment: Hi Ferdinand, sorry for wasting your time. Queues working fine, problem came in for me with something completely unrelated. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Chris, yes, but I don't know how to close a question.....

Comment: @MichaelFranze: Under your question's tags (python, initialization...) there should be a few links like "link", "edit", "close", "delete"... Use `delete`.

Comment: You do not have 250 reputation yet which is required to close your own questions; in the meantime, you can either delete them if there are no answers, or flag them for moderator attention using the flag link. I've closed your question for you.